# java.awt.Robot thread can't be stopped/destroyed?

Tags: java, thread-safety, awtrobot

I made desktop remote control aplication using java.awt.Robot, and is working fine.
Application is integrated in another application system so I want to be able to start/stop remote control from outer system and I found strange problem - I can't stop Robot.

I tried several things: running it inside thread (so I can stop thread), making robot object null and than calling System.gc() but the problem isn't with reference it's robot thread that is still running (after all others are destroyed).
In debug I can see running thread : Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running).

Here is code that will reproduce my problem:

```
public class RobotDestroy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Has anybody expirienced somthing similar ?
Any solutions ?

thanks

**edit:**

Here is example of running Robot in a thread that can be stopped **but a Robot instance is still running:**

```
public class RobotDestroy {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RobotThread rt = new RobotThread();
    rt.start(); 

    try {
        //do some work before thread shut down
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    rt.shutdown();          
}

private static class RobotThread extends Thread {

    public Robot robot;
    volatile boolean alive;

    public RobotThread(){
        try {
            this.robot = new Robot();
            this.alive = true;
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){

        while(alive){
            System.out.println("alive");
            try{
                robot.delay(5000);
                sleep(1000);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        this.alive = false;
        robot = null;
        System.out.println("shutdown");
    }       
}
```

}

**edit 2**

I tried what doctor killer suggested and although it is a good suggestion Robot thread is still running. Best way to prove it is to print-out threads before creating robot instance and after:

```
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(threadArray[i].getName());
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
After a lot of debugging I realized that problem isn't in java.awt.Robot class - it is java.awt.Toolkit that starts AWT-Window thread that remains running after application ends.
Robot object has RobotPeer (java.awt.peer.RobotPeer) which is returned by : ((ComponentFactory)toolkit).createRobot(this, screen);

Comment: Yes: exactly the same thing happened [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechagodzilla), and [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_HyyDHyAwI6k/SZnu_pMw9KI/AAAAAAAAEus/M8qTqLxXyjs/s1600/killer+robot.jpg)

Comment: Unstoppable robots? This is not good.

Comment: I have no immediate evidence at hand, but I would suggest tat Robot is actually starting another non-daemon thread (and, if I'm not wrong, it's starting the AWT EventQueue). While you can deterrence an instance if Robot, the only way I know ofto stop the EventQueue a va System.exit

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to stop execution inside the remaining thread to see what it is actually doing? This might give a hint on why it isn't shutting down.

Comment: After you last update, it looks like you identified the source of the problem...but how did you solve it? I.e. how did you eventually stop the AWT-Window thread?

Answer (score 0):

usually you would put a flag in your while(true) loop of the thread that receive the remote events so you would have something like while(isAlive) ... read remote event ... if remote event is disconnect you then get out of the loop and the robot would not get commands anymore.

The Robot is only still alive because your program keep calling it...your's to stop the loop

Also include this in your RobotThread

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class RobotDestroy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet(); Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]); for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) { System.out.println("Init " + threadArray[i].getName()); }
        RobotThread rt = new RobotThread();
        rt.start(); 

        // Listen to the upcomming commands...and push them to the RobotThread

        rt.shutdown();          
    }

    private static class RobotThread extends Thread {

        public Robot robot;

        public RobotThread(){
            try {
                this.robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run(){
            Command currentCommand = getNextCommand();
            while(currentCommand.getType() != CommandType.KILL){
                // Process the command no sleep...
                // ...
                // ...

                currentCommand = getNextCommand();
            }

            System.out.println("DIED ");
        }

        private LinkedList<Command> commands = new LinkedList<Command>();

        enum CommandType {
            KILL,
            DO_SOMETHING
        }

        private synchronized Command getNextCommand() {
            while(commands.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("WAITING");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return commands.removeFirst();
        }

        public synchronized void pushCommand(Command comm) {
            commands.addLast(comm);
            notify();
        }

        public synchronized void shutdown(){
            commands.clear();
            pushCommand(new Command(CommandType.KILL));
            System.out.println("shutdown");
            //Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet(); Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]); for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) { System.out.println("End " + threadArray[i].getName()); }
        }  

        class Command {
            private CommandType cmdType;
            public Command(CommandType type) {
                this.cmdType = type;
            }
            public CommandType getType() { return cmdType; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not correct. I have a thread that is listening for remote events, and when I stop it Robot is still alive :)
I can post example source but believe me it is like that.

Comment: Robot's still alive because it starts a non-daemon thread that you don't have control of, not amount cohesion is going to stop it ;)

Comment: What do you mean by Robot is still alive: Robot is an object not a Thread: please post more code (listening thread alone)

Comment: Is there any way to stop that thread (beside System.exit(0)) ?
Or should I look for Robot alternative ?

Comment: I think there is some confusion between Thread and Robot...your Robot is in a Thread...right? Then it is your duty to add some code to get out of the robot thread when needed...the stop() method of Thread is depricated and clearly explains that it is your responsibility to end the loop

Comment: As I've already stated, Robot is launching a new, non-daemon thread, AKA the Event Dispatching Thread, this thread s automatically generated when you start interacting with the UI, you don't have control over this thread, so even when the thread your executing in ends, it will leave the EDT running. I know of no way to stop this thread other then System.exit

Comment: @doctorkiller I updated my post with example of thread so take a look. thank you

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks I am affraid that your answers are correct :) Any alternative for Robot ?

Comment: @dux none that I'm aware of. Any solution is going to run into the same problem, they will all need to generate a EventQueue in order to dispatch events to UI components or OS

Comment: @dux I understand that your code now works properly?
Have you considered using some synchronization technique to wake and suspend your RobotThread?

Comment: @doctorkiller sorry I wasn't clear - I didn't solve my problem, thread is stopped but Robot instance is still running.

Comment: @dux I added some code you might be interested into adding in your RobotThread to process the Commands in a FIFO structure

Comment: @dux there was an error in my code for the shutdown: it works now

Comment: @doctorkiller I don't know doctor, I must be doing something wrong but after running Your code i still have 4 threads running:
1. AWT-Windows
2. Thread-4
3. EventQueueMonitor-ComponentEvtDispatch
4. DestroyJavaVM

Comment: @doctorkiller You are trying to say that after you call shutdown you don't have any threads alive and program exits ?